# Angular data- prefix attribute access

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a simple controller wanting to access a variable that was assigned with `data-` prefix (from server). The below code shows `undefined`. Why is it and how to access `myId` in this case? If `data-my-id="12345"` is the wrong way to do it then what is the right way?

Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/i4cAKgmJ1va7SHbz9h6y?p=preview

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p data-my-id="12345">Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'My Id is ' + $scope.myId;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your premise that `data-X` should initiate a `X` value on the scope is wrong.
When angular compiles the DOM it checks if there is a directive definition that matches X.
In your case there is no `myIdDirective`, so no functionality is being attached to that element, just a regular element with attributes.

In this case even `ngInit` would not help, because controllers are instantiated before the pre-linking phase.

#### You can use `$attrs` to get an attribute value like so:

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/I1YxwWPEVFFYZAXgQJRU?p=preview

**Template:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" data-my-id="12345">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$attrs) {
  $scope.name = 'My Id is ' + $attrs.myId;
});
```

Comment: It must be too late at night coding. I got messed up between `$scope` and `$attrs` ...LOL

Answer (score 1):

If this is absolutely needed then you can do it quick and dirty by giving the `<p>` tag a controller and using $attrs:

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fyXsVRahqYvBYbcatGqb?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner angular way of doing this is to create a angular directive and read the value from there. You really shouldn't interact directly with the DOM using an angular controller.

When you create a new directive, your can set the `restrict` property to `A`, and name it `dataMyId` so it will bind to any element with `data-my-id` attribute.

Then, you can access the property value from the directive's controller.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to use a directive like

```
<p data-my-id="12345" my-id>Hello {{name}}!</p>
```

And define it like

```
app.directive('myId', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.name = 'My Id is ' + attr.myId;
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rz9JT/1/)